# Is the technology behind the Shuttle's heat-shielding tiles used in any product today?

Tags: space-shuttle, technology, materials, heat-shield, spinoff

Many NASA inventions have had subsequent lives in the commercial marketplace. Have the Space Shuttle's heat-shielding tiles also had a second life?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a [Spinoffs from the Space Shuttle Program](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/news/background/facts/SpinoffsFromTheShuttleFS.html) page hosted on the [NASA Marshall Space Flight Center](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/home/index.html) portal. According to it:

> **Jewelry Design** — Jewelers no longer have to worry about inhaling dangerous asbestos fibers from the blocks they use as soldering bases.
>   Space Shuttle heat shield tiles offer jewelers a safer soldering base
>   with temperature resistance far beyond the 1,400 degrees Fahrenheit
>   generated by the jeweler's torch.

There is also:

> **Automotive Insulation** — Materials from the Space Shuttle thermal protection system are being used on NASCAR racing cars to protect
>   drivers from the extreme heat generated by the engines.

But the latter isn't specific about the Space Shuttle heat shield tiles (aka HRSI - High-temperature Reusable Surface Insulation) and I believe they're referring to the use of Reinforced Carbon–Carbon (RCC) composites and Flexible Insulation Blankets (FIB) here. [NASA at NASCAR](http://www.nasa.gov/topics/nasalife/features/nasa-nascar.html) page isn't much more specific on this, but it does list some other [NASA Spinoff](http://spinoff.nasa.gov/) technologies that benefit the National Association for Stock Car Auto Racing, from fire-resistant materials for race car drivers and pit crew suits to better brakes and safer tires.

There is an additional, indirect benefit to the industry developed for the HRSI tiles:

> **Product Labeling** — NASA needs to identify, track, and keep records on each of the thousands of heat-shield tiles on the Space Shuttle.
>   This required a labeling system that could be put on ceramic material
>   and withstand the rigors of space travel to be readable after a
>   flight. NASA developed high data-density, two-dimensional,
>   machine-readable symbol technology used to mark individual tiles. This
>   novel method of labeling products with invisible and virtually
>   indestructible markings can be used on electronic parts,
>   pharmaceuticals and livestock -- in fact on just about anything.

Source: [Space Shuttle Program Benefits Industry and Health](http://fas.org/news/usa/2000/usa-001012.htm). You can read more about this laser-etched symbol coding, dubbed *"compressed symbologies"*, now commercialized labeling / identification system through a [NASA Space Act](http://www.nasa.gov/open/plan/space-act.html) agreement, on [NASA Spinoff](http://spinoff.nasa.gov/spinoff1998/ch1.htm). I'm reproducing a shot excerpt here for convenience:

> Compressed symbologies can withstand extreme fluctuations of
>   temperatures, up to 2,200 degrees Fahrenheit and an air flow exceeding
>   18,000 miles per hour. That is the heat load and speed associated with
>   a Shuttle orbiter during a space mission.
>
> The coding technology provides up to 100 times as much information as
>   linear bar coding symbology in the same or less space. Markings can
>   range in size from a mere four microns (read microscopically) to as
>   large as two square feet (read telescopically).